# How to use XSLT contains with multiple XMLNS

Tags: xml, xslt, contains

This is the XML file we are trying to manipulate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pois xmlns="urn:schemas-etourist:Poi">
<Poi PID="1234567">
.......
<Kategorien xmlns="urn:schemas-etourist:SchemaExtension>
    <Kategorie xmlns="">
    <Bezeichnung>Museen</Bezeichnung>
    <Ebene>1</Ebene>
    <KategorieID>28</KategorieID>
    <Kategorie xmlns="">
    <Bezeichnung>Galerie</Bezeichnung>
    <Ebene>2</Ebene>
    <KategorieID>225</KategorieID>
    <Kategorie xmlns="">
    <Bezeichnung>Sammlung</Bezeichnung>
    <Ebene>3</Ebene>
    <KategorieID>56</KategorieID>
</Kategorien>
</Poi>
</Pois>
```

And here is our XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:td="urn:schemas-etourist:Poi"
xmlns:td2="urn:schemas-etourist:SchemaExtension"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
extension-element-prefixes="php">

<xsl:template match="/td:Pois">
<xsl:apply-templates disable-output-escaping="yes" select="td:Poi/td2:Kategorien/td2:Kategorie[contains(td2:Bezeichnung, 'Museen')]">
<xsl:sort select="td:OBJECT_TEXT_NAME"></xsl:sort>
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td:Poi">
....
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do we get the template to select only "Pois" which have a "Kategorie" which contains "Museen"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Produces an empty result

Answer (score 1):

> td:Poi/td2:Kategorien/td2:Kategorie[contains(td2:Bezeichnung, 'Museen')]

Your elements Kategorie and Bezeichnung are not in a namespace, so you should remove the `"td2:"` prefixes.

At least, that's what I'm assuming. Your Kategorie elements don't seem to have any end tags, so there's something gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Took us a while to get back to this one. Thanks for the answer. The end tags are complete (our mistake). Removing the td2 from Kategorie and Bezeichnung only outputs '1' & '28', the values for <Ebene> & <KategorieID>. Any more ideas..??

Comment: You're still displaying XML that isn't well formed. Are you expecting me to somehow know what the actual XML looks like, when you have shown me something different?